# How to get Id in modal from list when open the modal pop up in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have table where I have list of records. When I click on delete link, I want to open the modal pop up with relevant record name.

Currently, it always grabs the first record value from list in the modal.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HorseName)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Action")
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            @item.HorseName
        </td>

        <td>
            <a data-target="#HorseTrackerModal" data-toggle="modal" style="cursor:pointer">Delete</a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="HorseTrackerModal" role="dialog">
                <div id="dialogbox" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Are you sure you want to delete @item.HorseName?
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>

                            <a href="#" class="delete" data-id="@item.TrackerId" style="cursor:pointer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Yes</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "HorseTracker")';
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
    debugger;
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $.post(url, { id: id }, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            row.remove();
        }
    }).fail(function (response) {
        alert("Can not delete record!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html (in your case `<div id="HorseTrackerModal" .. >` and `<button id="reset" ..>`

Comment: And why are you creating a modal in each iteration. You should only have one.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Sorry how to do this. Please guide me.

Comment: There are obviously scripts associated with this - they need to be included in your question

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I will add those script in question now.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please have a look. I have added script.

Comment: That script has nothing to do with the modal

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have only this script which I want to execute when I click on `yes` in the modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178493/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-frame).

Comment: No need to render HTML of modal for each item. That is giving unnecessary work to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is rendering HTML markup needed for modal dialog for each item in your collection! That means the browser has to parse and render the HTML which might not even be shown to the user. **Always try to render the minimum HTML (less number of DOM nodes) to get one step closer to provide a fast web experience**

IMHO, You should consider a **lazy/as needed loading** approach. That means, when user clicks on the delete link, that is when you will render the HTML needed for the modal dialog. You can make an ajax call to your server where it will render this HTML markup.

So let's add an action method, which will return the HTML needed for confirm modal.

```
public ActionResult ConfirmDelete(int id)
{
    var u = db.Horses.Find(id);
    return PartialView(u);
}
```

and in the `ConfirmDelete.cshtml` partial view, which is strongly typed to the Horse object, you will render the HTML markup for the modal dialog in that.

```
@model YourNamespace.Horse

<div id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Confirm/h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>
                    Are you sure to delete @Model.Name
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form action="@Url.Action("Delete")" id="form-delete">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id" />

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here i am passing the entity object to the partial view, You can change that to just pass the `Id` which you received as the parameter if needed. (You may also accept the name and id as params and pass that to the view , instead of querying the table again). Pass via ViewBag/Viewmodel as appropriate. It is your call.

Let's make some adjustments to the HTML markup where you list the data in your main view. First, i will try to give an Id to each of the table row's so that we can remove this table row later when user confirms the delete operation via the modal dialog. I will give the format of `"row-{item.Id}"` for the Id value.

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr id="row-@item.Id">
       <td> @item.HorseName</td>
       <td>
           <a class="modal-link" 
              href="@Url.Action("ConfirmDelete",new { id=item.Id})">Delete</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

Now add the relevant JavaScript to fire up this modal. We will listen to any link element with the CSS clas `modal-link`, read the `href` value and make an ajax call to that url (the `ConfirmDelete` action). Once we get the response, we will call the `modal` method on that (the HTML markup came back)

```
$(function () {

    $('body').on('click', 'a.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#modal").remove();
        var url=$(this).attr("href");
        $.get(url, function (data) {

            $(data).modal();
        });
    });

    // to do : handle "delete form"

 });
```

Now when user clicks on delete link, they will see the confirmation dialog. The HTML markup returned by the confirm action has a form tag inside that. So let's add some more JavaScript code to handle that.

Replace `// to do : handle "delete form"` part with the below code.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#form-delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url =$(this).attr("action");
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var id = $(this).find("[name='id']").val();

    var $row =$('#row-'+id);  // Get the table row

    $.post(url, data).done(function (res) {
        if(res.status==="success")
        {
            $row.fadeOut();
            $("#modal").modal('hide');
        }
        else
        {
            alert(res.message);
        }
     });
});
```

Assuming your `Delete` action returns a JSON response like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
       // to do : code to remove from db
       return Json(new { status = "success"});
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       // to do : log ex
       return Json(new { status = "error", message = "Error deleting"});
    }
}
```